# JBoss Compiles but NoClassDefFoundError on startup

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, websocket, jboss

I have an ejb project (built with maven) I am attempting to deploy in jboss 7.1 EAP app server (via eclipse ui).  I can successfully build the jar (mvn clean install) with dependencies on a websocket implementation, as well as running a singleton bean on startup (annotating it with @Startup and putting a println in constructor works).  However, when I start the server with code that uses the maven dependency, it throws a NoClassDefFoundError.  Any ideas?

pom.xml source

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.connor.wstest</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebSocketEJB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>    
    <dependencies>
    <!-- official socket.io java implementation (ported from original javascript) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
      <artifactId>socket.io-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>  
        </dependencies> 
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>ejbModule</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
              <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Error Stack Trace (only occurs when deploying ejb to jboss app server and having code reference imported library):

```
1:13,929 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."CryptoWs.jar".component.StartupOne.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CryptoWs.jar".component.StartupOne.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint$1.proceed(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldManagedReferenceFactory.create(WeldManagedReferenceFactory.java:51)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldConstructionStartInterceptor$1.aroundConstruct(WeldConstructionStartInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallback(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:109)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:112)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.produce(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContext.produce(WeldInjectionContext.java:46)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldConstructionStartInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldConstructionStartInterceptor.java:37)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:26)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.StartupCountDownInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupCountDownInterceptor.java:25)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/socket/client/IO
    at com.connor.StartupOne.<init>(StartupOne.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.socket.client.IO from [Module "deployment.CryptoWs.jar" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 56 more

22:41:13,950 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "CryptoWs.jar")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"CryptoWs.jar\".component.StartupOne.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/socket/client/IO
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.socket.client.IO from [Module \"deployment.CryptoWs.jar\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
22:41:14,013 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "CryptoWs.jar" (runtime-name : "CryptoWs.jar")
22:41:14,013 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."CryptoWs.jar".component.StartupOne.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
```

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
package com.connor;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class StartupOne
 */
@Singleton
@Asynchronous
@Startup
public class StartupOne {



    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public StartupOne() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Socket socket;

        System.out.println("***" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try {
            socket = IO.socket("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=instrument"); //THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION!!!!!!


             socket
                .on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, args -> {
                    /*
                    Map<String, Object> eventArgs = new HashMap<>();

                    eventArgs.put("subs", Arrays.asList(subscriptions));

                    socket.emit("SubAdd", eventArgs);
                    */
                })
                .on("m", args -> Stream.of(args).forEach(arg -> {
                    // Log the raw message for debug
                    System.out.println("Raw message: "+arg);

                    //CryptoCompareResponse response = CryptoCompareResponse.unpack((String) arg);
                    //if (response.getMessageType() == 5 && (response.getFlag() == 1 || response.getFlag() == 2)) {
                    //    updatePricing(response);
                    //}
                }))
                .on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, args -> System.out.println("Received disconnect event"));

            socket.connect();   
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You must not place initialisation code of your EJB in the constructor. You have to use the postConstruct callback method to do so (see EJB spec).

Comment: Open your deployed app (ear file) in your jboss deployment folder and check if it contains those libs you need inside the lib folder.

Comment: Where is the `io.socket.client.IO` class located? If it's not in the `CryptoWs.jar` then you need to add it as a module or make an EAR with the `CryptoWs.jar` and the library in the `EAR/lib` directory.

Answer (score 2):

The root Exception is `ClassNotFoundException` and it tells you, that your deployment `CryptoWs.jar` can not find the class `io.socket.client.IO`. So where is that class? It is in the jar `socket.io-client-1.0.0.jar`. But where is that jar in context of jboss? The answer is, not available. Now you have different options.

1. Create a war archive out of `WebSocketEJB`. The jar should then be added to the lib folder of the war archive.
2. Create a jboss module for socket.io-client and let WebSocketEJB point to it. (manifest entry)
3. Create an uber jar.

I would suggest you give it a try with option 1.